# unexpected behavior of margin-top css property

Tags: html, css

I am facing very simple problem with `margin-top` and its freaking me out. I have simplified my document to make it readable.
Here is my structure of html document

```
<body>
    <section>

    </section>

    <section>
        <div></div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS

```
section{
    width: 100%;
    height:768px;
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
    position: relative;
}

div{
    background-color:green;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;

    margin-top:0px;
}
```

When `div`'s `margin-top` is 0, it looks like this:
[image]

But when I change it to `margin-top` to `10px`, it looks like this:[image]

I could not point out how that white space is added. Inspection shows that it is the part of body. Section is actually pushed down. I was expecting that small div to be pushed down relative to section. Can anyone explain this weired behavior?

Comment: You can give a class to `div` & apply the style.

Comment: I know I can do that, I was just simplifying the problem so others could read it properly

Comment: Have you tried applying relative positioning to the div and giving it a top of 10px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [From `w3.org`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or
>   might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins
>   that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined
>   margin is called a collapsed margin.

Now to prevent collapsed margin, you should add `overflow:auto` to the parent element.

Comment: So in my case margin of div and section are collapsing? How is this useful?

Comment: @bipin Exactly, any margin rules applied on `div` it is as if you applied them on its parent `section`.

Comment: @bipin: You can use display property to prevent this problem. (i.e "display: inline-block;"). Try in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PRnN3/

Answer (score 1):

here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/suriyag/UhqX9/1/ that has solution for your requirements

```
    section{
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:768px;
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
    position: relative;
}

div{
    position:absolute; 
    top:10px;
    background-color:green;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
  }
```

did some little changes in your code

Comment: please fix the css code first you have at least 2 errors

Comment: now i fixed those errors that was happened while pasting now check it

Answer (score 0):

try

```
float: left;
```

for section tag if you can

http://jsfiddle.net/dcTw3/2/